# why unity2d needs camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas, camera

I am a beginner in unity that I want to make a 2d simple game

I began with creating a canvas and found things displayed in the game is **exactly what in the canvas**.

So, **what's the use of the main camera** then? I tried to delete it and it told me "no camera rending"

[image]

by the way, why is the canvas transform locked?

[image]

I am way out stupid beginning with unity. Thanks for anyone that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canvas uses the main camera to resolve its screen scaling and adapt to the resolution of the screen. I believe if you're using it on an editor, canvas resolves it to the current size of the game screen ui.

The transform in canvas is disabled if it's on Screen or Camera render mode. It will be enabled once you use the canvas in world mode.